# Navigation bar issue iphone 4.3

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios4, navigationbar

I am now developing an app which support both iOS 4.3 and 5.0.

My code works fine with 5.0, but results in a tricky-bug in 4.3.

Issue is:

I've got a view with a tableView in it. This view have a navigation bar with both left and right navigation bar items. Once I select the row in table view (and reaches it's corresponding view) and returns back, both the left and right navigation-bar items "vanish".

I've been over this mess for last few hours, some one got a cure?

This is what I have already done:

This is the utility method that I call when view loads.

```
+ (void)setNavigationBarContents:(UIViewController *)view 
{


UIImage *topBarimage=[UIImage imageNamed:NAVIGATION_BAR_IMAGE];


if([view.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]) {

    [view.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:topBarimage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
else 
{
    [view.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:topBarimage] aboveSubview:view.navigationController.navigationBar];

}

UIImage *logo=[UIImage imageNamed:LOGO];
UIImageView *logoView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:logo];
view.navigationItem.titleView = logoView;

UIImage *settingsButtonImage= [UIImage imageNamed:NAVIGATION_SETTINGS];   
UIButton *rightBarButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[rightBarButton setBackgroundImage: settingsButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[rightBarButton addTarget: view action:@selector(settingsButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
rightBarButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 40);  
view.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: rightBarButton];

UIImage *logoutButtonImage= [UIImage imageNamed:LOGOUT];
UIButton *leftBarButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[leftBarButton setBackgroundImage: logoutButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[leftBarButton addTarget: view action:@selector(logout:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
leftBarButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 32);  
view.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: leftBarButton];


}
```

Have tried calling this both in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear, but in vain.

This is how I call this in viewController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

//other setups here.

[Utility setNavigationBarContents:self]; 

}
```

Comment: Try this code in ViewWillAppear  [Utility setNavigationBarContents:self];

Comment: I have already tried this as I told earlier. Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: Only bar button item vanishes or Navigation bar vanishing?

Comment: Only bar button items. But titleView is there

Comment: Have you tried using without class methods (utility method), Just intialize in your viewcontroller didload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution by adding
This code in my appDelegate.m

```
// added so that navigation bar background image works in version lower than 5.0

@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:NAVIGATION_BAR_IMAGE];
[img drawInRect:rect];
}
@end
```